# Using a particular order for a proof involving a logical and compound statement

Tags: logic, solution-verification

I am trying to prove a conditional statement by contradiction. Because it is a conditional, p->q, and to prove by contradiction, I have the negated statement of p and not q, I am having trouble starting with p, and making my way to not q, in the proof. As it is now in logical and form, can I switch the two simple statements, to have not q and p, and move from not q to p through my proof?

The original statement was

> For integer n, if 7n+4 is even, then n is even.

In attempting to prove this by contradiction, I negate the statement and have a new statement I am trying to prove, but which produces a contradiction:

> For integer n, 7n+4 is even, and n is odd.

Comment: Can you share the conditional you're trying to prove? Also, what do you mean by "prove a conditional statement"? Are you trying to prove that your conditional is a tautology, or are you trying to deduce it from another set of statements? Also, what rules of inference/replacement are you allowed to use in your proof?

Comment: I have updated my question to provide the original statement, and its negation, which by trying to prove the latter, I would arrive at a contradiction. It would seem harder for me to work from 7n+4 is even, to n is odd, than the other way around. My apologies if this is hard to understand: this is my first time asking a question in this form, on this resource.

Comment: You’re fine! Welcome to Math StackExchange!

Comment: So, when I read this comment from another thread:
"In a "genuine" proof by contradiction, you assume both  and ¬, and deduce some other contradiction ∧¬."
It occurs to me that when I am moving from the conditional to the logical and statement, I no longer have a hypothesis implies conclusion, but that now I might have a hypothesis of two simple statements, and a conclusion which is presenting the contradiction. Does that sound workable?

Comment: You have correctly written down the  "and" statement you hope to get a contradiction from.

Comment: And the contradiction would be the new conclusion I would end the proof with?